# DIV background-color won't change when hovering if I set it in advance

Tags: php, css

I would like a DIV's `background-color` to change when I hover over it. I can get it to work if I don't set the `background-color` in the DIV's `style` property but I don't understand why this stops the hover colour from being applied?

```
<style>
.hovery {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.hovery:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
</style>
```

When I create my `DIV` (in PHP) I'm using the code below and I'm setting the `background-color` property at the time of creation so that I can set the 'selected' one to a different colour than all the other DIVs:

```
echo "<div class='hovery' style='background-color: " . ($onthis==$shrow['Name'] ? $_SESSION['branding_buttonColour'] : "#EEEEFF;"). " '>\r\n";
```

I've discovered that if I **don't** set the `background-color` in the code above then the hover colour-change works, but why does setting the `background-color` prevent the `hover` colour from working? Aren't they two different things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called **specificity** and you are giving the whole strength to the inline styling. Avoid it or make javascript tricks (like on hover adding a classname). You can make too this:

```
.hovery:hover {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

But I don't like it so much. If the inline styles are mandatory for your requirements, use `!important`. Otherwise, remove the inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You're best off adding a class to the element within PHP, then controlling the `background-color` of that class with CSS.

The added benefits of this is keeping your code clean, avoiding use of inline styles (which over-rides every rule) and you can easily change the class via Javascript which in turn changes the color.